# JQuery: Text color toggle on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Probably simple one, just trying to animate the color of text on hovering over a div. Got so far researching on SO but if someone could point me in the right direction that would be awesome. Currently this does nothing and throws no errors to the console:

```
$('#homenav .homenavimg').hover(function (){
    $('#homenav h1').toggle(function() {
       $(this).animate({ color: "#FF0000" }, 1000);
    }, function() {
       $(this).animate({ color: "#000000" }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!
(PS: I have links to JQuery and UI set up ok)

Comment: `.toggle()` Description: Display or hide the matched elements. - from the docs. http://api.jquery.com/toggle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would have provided your markup that would have been great but check this out. Probably you are looking for something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/j6AeZ/2/

```
$('#homenav .homenavimg').hover(function (){
$('#homenav h1').stop().animate({ color: "#FF0000" }, 1000);
  }, function() {
  $('#homenav h1').stop().animate({ color: "#000000" }, 1000);
});​
```

Comment: add the .stop() before the animate, it's always a good practice :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#homenav .homenavimg').hover(function (){
    $('#homenav h1').stop().animate({ color: "#FF0000" }, 1000);
 }, function() {
    $('#homenav h1').stop().animate({ color: "#000000" }, 1000);
});
```

No need to use the `.toggle()`, and you were using it wrong before anyway.

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uArDu/2/

Comment: the "jumpToEnd" does not produce a nice behavior though !

Comment: `.stop(true,true)` generally prevents an animation bug... but I see that bug isn't present in color animation.

Answer (score 0):

If anyones interested in turning this into a navigation style effect (ie works on more then one h1) do the following:

```
$('#homenav .homenavimg').hover(function (){
$(this).find('h1').stop().animate({ color: "#53799E" }, 250);
 }, function() {
  $(this).find('h1').stop().animate({ color: "#F58426" }, 250);
});
```